# server.py says "unicodedecodeerror 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3 invalid continuation byte"

Tags: python, server

[image: Windows 10 command line]

When run from Windows 10 command line as a module, server.py says

> unicodedecodeerror 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3 invalid continuation byte

Done this before on Windows 7 and then on the same machine updated to Windows 10 and had no problems.

- Some hints point out to 0xe9 being a non-UTF8 character coding (is Latin-1's é, but this character shouldn't be on server.py!).
- Some others say it's because of the \U character in the address (C:\Users... tried moving the file to root and same issue still happens.)
- Some others say it is a server issue related on the port used (8000 or 8080).
- Some others point to the machine's coding (Latin-1 in my case. Have other Windows 10 MX Spanish machine and no issue has shown up).

Up to now, I've found no concrete solution to this issue.

Comment: What is your computer (host) name?

Comment: yikes!... it's 'Lobo-con-café' formatted this netbook and changed it. original was CaffeWolf... Such a simple issue yet something I missed completely. think you hit the spot. will change host name and retry.